# Task scheduler ("Run whether user is logged on or not") on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

My PC is not password protected (because it's for the family), and whenever I create a task on task scheduler with "Run whether user is logged on or not" it asks me to enter a password. How Can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a user account with a password. Make it a member of the Administrator's group.

Now log into this new user, set up a Task and set it to run for any user.

This should work as Administrators can create Tasks to run for other users.

Once the Task has been established, there should not be any need to further manage it.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. But is there any other solution other than this one?

Comment: I do not think so. You need an Admin User with a password.  This is why I suggest a secondary user id so you can do this.

Comment: Remember the task will not (should not) require further management once set up.

Comment: I did like you told me, I created a user as an administrator, and I created a task with "Run whether user is logged on or not", but the task didn't execute, even if I right-click on it and click on"execute". Why?

Comment: Compare your task with tasks that are part of the Windows setup and do execute.

Comment: I compared, they are the same. Still not working.

Comment: I do not know what is wrong with your setup. I have a number of vendor tasks that kick off as they should.

Comment: I solved it by adding the user account to "Log on as a batch job"

Comment: Your initial question was "How to set a task without a password) and I have shown you how to set a task with an Admin ID.  So I think my answer was at least helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a new user account as administrator and adding it to "Log on as a batch job".